# SQL CASE WHEN IN (SELECT...) THEN

Tags: sql, case, databricks

I am not an expert on sql, but I have not found a similar issue, maybe it is too obvious...
So here is my question:

I have a couple of temp views like 'contract_ids_canceled' or 'contract_ids_changed_date' with contract ids. And I have a big table with all those contract ids and more.
Now I want to kind of 'tag' them in a new column. I have tried the following:

```
CASE WHEN contractid in (SELECT DISTINCT contractid FROM contract_ids_canceled) THEN 'contract canceled' 
     WHEN contractid in (SELECT blabla) THEN 'contract changed'
END as updates
```

but I get the following error message

> Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: IN/EXISTS predicate sub-queries can only be used in Filter/Join and a few commands:

If I am using something like

```
IN (1,2,3)
```

then the IN works, so I am a bit lost why the SELECT statement in the CASE is not working and about the error message... Would be nice if someone could help me out here!

Databricks SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As error indicates, Databricks does not support subqueries using `IN` or `EXISTS` in `CASE` statements. As an alternative, consider outer joining each view to master contract table:

```sql
SELECT m.contractid,
       CASE 
          WHEN cncl.contractid IS NOT NULL 
          THEN 'contract canceled'
          WHEN dt.contractid IS NOT NULL 
          THEN 'contract date changed'
       END AS contract_status
       
FROM master_contracts m     
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT contractid
    FROM contract_ids_canceled
)  cncl 
  ON m.contractid = cncl.contractid
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT contractid
    FROM contract_ids_changed_date
) dt
  ON m.contractid = dt.contractid
```

Comment: Thank you Parfait! I must have misunderstood the non supported sub queries, I thought the IN itself does not work but that works just fine without the subquery.